# Copying .zip file using sharp ssh

Tags: c#, ssh

I am facing a problem in copying a Zip file from linux machine to Windows machine using C#.
here are my :

1) Get filename by using 
   sftp.getFiles(sourcepath).
   filename=item.to string();
   sourcepath=sourcspath+filename;
   sftp.Get(sourcepath,destination);
It is working for a single file, which will be enumerated by sftp.getfile();
But when i do Zip the folder and try to copy that .Zip file with the sftp.Get(sourcepath,destination)
 it is not working,
Cheked with the sourcepath it is correct and ccheked the permisions of ZIp file it has all permissions.
Please let me know how can we overcome the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using below library.

http://sshnet.codeplex.com/

This is a very rich library which support more functionality compared to sharp ssh.

Comment: Yes, Even sharpssh worked , the filename should not have backslash.